# WordPress - Hide personal settings from profile page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook

In profile page (where user could edit his details) there is part "Personal options"  with "Admin color scheme" etc.

I know how to remove it with CSS / jQuery.

How could i remove that part with a hook/ filter / php code ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
// removes the `profile.php` admin color scheme options
remove_action( 'admin_color_scheme_picker', 'admin_color_scheme_picker' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'cor_remove_personal_options' ) ) {
  /**
   * Removes the leftover 'Visual Editor', 'Keyboard Shortcuts' and 'Toolbar' options.
   */
  function cor_remove_personal_options( $subject ) {
    $subject = preg_replace( '#<h3>Personal Options</h3>.+?/table>#s', '', $subject, 1 );
    return $subject;
  }

  function cor_profile_subject_start() {
    ob_start( 'cor_remove_personal_options' );
  }

  function cor_profile_subject_end() {
    ob_end_flush();
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_head-profile.php', 'cor_profile_subject_start' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-profile.php', 'cor_profile_subject_end' );
```

Found here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49643/remove-personal-options-section-from-profile

**UPDATE**

Here is a JS (jQuery to be exact) hack as well...

```
function hide_personal_options(){
    echo "\n" . '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function($) { $(\'form#your-profile > h3:first\').hide(); $(\'form#your-profile > table:first\').hide(); $(\'form#your-profile\').show(); });</script>' . "\n";
}
add_action('admin_head','hide_personal_options');
```

Found here:

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-simplify-wordpress-profiles-by-removing-personal-options/

Comment: Thanks, iv'e seen this answer, the thing its "hackey" because its basically missing with the HTML output, and remove content with "preg_replace".  I'm looking for something more "elegant" if exist.

Comment: There is nothing "elegant" unfortunately... it's all hacks.  Removing the actual code prevents anyone from being able to physically make changes.  I think it's a cleaner approach than using JS or CSS as those can be turned off and changes can still be made.